# Select values from column like {"key1":value1,"key2":value2, }?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I select values from column that looks like:

```
{"key1":value1,"key2":value2, }
```

in PLSQL?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. Following that a a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting  satisfactory answer. In this case your question is very unclear, and lacks any necessary supporting details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *looks like* a JSON. If it really is, then such a test case shows how to do that. Note that you need Oracle 12c or higher.

```
create table test (col varchar2(100));

alter table test add constraint ch_json check (col is json);

insert into test values ('{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}');

select col, json_value(col, '$.key1') as value from test;
```

Comment: The format of the column is varchar and also there are different columns in this table.

Comment: OK, I'm glad to hear that.